# Possible data race в Valgrind

Tags: c, pthread, unix, valgrind

Сталкивался ли кто, чтобы  при запуске программы под Valgrind, сообщения типа "Possible data race" указывали на функции блокирования/разблокирования мьютексов? В мане вроде ясно сказано, что Valgrind прекрасно работает с Posix-потоками, но функции *pthread_mutex_lock/unlock* ему явно не нравятся, или я что-то упускаю?

```
Possible data race during write of size 4 at 0x64BC34 by thread #1
==11521== Locks held: none
==11521==    at 0x3A60A1: pthread_mutex_lock (in /lib/libthr.so.3)
==11521==    by 0x5C48E: pthread_mutex_lock (in /usr/local/lib/valgrind    /vgpreload_helgrind-x86-freebsd.so)
==11521==    by 0x8052651: md_mutex_operation (md_pthread.c:92)
==11521==    by 0x804D9ED: md_prt (md_funcs.c:49)
==11521==    by 0x804DFD6: md_freepthr_create (md_funcs.c:268)
==11521==    by 0x804B031: main (ml_shd.c:374)
==11521== 
==11521== This conflicts with a previous write of size 4 by thread #2
==11521== Locks held: none
==11521==    at 0x3A686A: ??? (in /lib/libthr.so.3)
==11521==    by 0x5C88E: pthread_mutex_unlock (in /usr/local/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-x86-freebsd.so)
==11521==    by 0x805278F: md_mutex_operation (md_pthread.c:118)
==11521==    by 0x804DAA4: md_prt (md_funcs.c:68)
==11521==    by 0x8054EEA: md_freepthr_func (md_pthread.c:1193)
==11521==    by 0x5F245: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-x86-freebsd.so)
==11521==    by 0x39F4B9: ??? (in /lib/libthr.so.3)
==11521== 
==11521== Address 0x64BC34 is 52 bytes inside a block of size 60 alloc'd
==11521==    at 0x5B6FA: calloc (in /usr/local/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-x86-freebsd.so)
==11521==    by 0x3A596C: ??? (in /lib/libthr.so.3)
==11521==    by 0x5EF68: pthread_mutex_init (in /usr/local/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-x86-freebsd.so)
==11521==    by 0x804C4D2: md_conninit (md_cfg.c:189)
==11521==    by 0x804A19E: main (ml_shd.c:62)
==11521== 
==11521== (action on error) vgdb me ... 
==11521== Continuing ...
```

Update :

```
#define MD_PRT(dlevel,fmt,...) \
  md_prt(dlevel,"%s (%s:%d): " fmt,\
    pname,__func__,__LINE__,##__VA_ARGS__)

void md_prt(uint32_t dlevel,const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list vp;

  md_mutex_operation(&(p_conn->log_mutex),MD_LOCK);

  va_start(vp,fmt);
  vsyslog(LOG_DEBUG,fmt,vp);
  va_end(vp);

  md_mutex_operation(&(p_conn->log_mutex),MD_UNLOCK);

  return;
}

int md_mutex_operation(p_mutex, operation)
  pthread_mutex_t *p_mutex;
  int operation;
{
  int res = 0;
  time_t sec;
  struct timespec tim;
  tim.tv_nsec = 0;

#ifdef ML_DEBUG
  char str[20];
#endif

  switch(operation){
  case MD_LOCK:
    res = pthread_mutex_lock(p_mutex);
#ifdef ML_DEBUG
    if(res)
      MD_PRT(MD_PRT_THREAD,"Error %d of locking mutex (%s, pthread %u)",
        res,str,pthread_self());
#endif
    break;
  case MD_TRYLOCK:
    res = pthread_mutex_trylock(p_mutex);
#ifdef ML_DEBUG
    if(res)
      MD_PRT(MD_PRT_THREAD,"Error %d of trying lock mutex (%s, pthread %u)",
        res,str,pthread_self());
#endif
    break;
 case MD_TIMLOCK:
    time(&sec);
    tim.tv_sec = sec + MD_LOCK_TIMEOUT;
   res = pthread_mutex_timedlock(p_mutex,&tim);
#ifdef ML_DEBUG
    if(res)
      MD_PRT(MD_PRT_THREAD,"Error %d of time locking mutex (%s, pthread %u)",
        res,str,pthread_self());
#endif
   break;
  case MD_UNLOCK:
    res = pthread_mutex_unlock(p_mutex);
#ifdef ML_DEBUG
    if(res)
      MD_PRT(MD_PRT_THREAD,"Error %d of unlocking mutex (%s, pthread %u)",
        res,str,pthread_self());
#endif
    break;
  default :
    break;
  }

  return(res);
}
```

Comment: Скорее не нравится 

    ==11521== This conflicts with a previous write of size 4 by thread #2
    ==11521== Locks held: none

Comment: да, но на вершине стека вызовов pthread_mutex_lock и unlock... функция *md_prt()* - захватывает мьютекс, записывает сообщение в лог, освобождает мьютекс. статические и глобальные переменные, помимо самого мьютекса, не используются, так что мне совершенно неясно, какой конфликт он нашел

Comment: Возможно я совсем не прав, но мне кажется, что отсюда
  
     md_mutex_operation (md_pthread.c:118)

должен был бы вызываться lock, а не unlock. Либо где-то раньше, на пути сюда lock не был вызван.

-

Никогда не работал с Valgrind, но подозреваю, что этот отладчик трассируя потоки отловил одновременную (или не защищенную никаким lock (он об этом пишет: 

    Locks held: none

)) запись по адресу в блок, полученный (кстати, это интересно) из pthread_mutex_init, который вызывался из md_conninit (md_cfg.c:189).

--

Но, еще раз, это догадки, т.к. Valgrind я никогда не использовал.

Comment: да, в том то и странность, что Valgrind ссылается на какую-то переменную, под которую выделяется память в pthread_mutex_init. md_mutex_operation - это просто моя обертка для вызовов lock/unlock, в которой проверяется результат операции.

Comment: @margosh, судя по стеку потоков это замечание к ошибке не относится, но IMHO странно вызывать MD_PRT() из md_mutex_operation(). 

Смотрите, если у Вас ошибка в операции с мьютексом, Вы хотите напечатать ее и опять косвенно выполняете операцию с (**возможно тем же**) мьютексом.

Я бы вообще мьютекс в md_prt сделал локальным статическим (лог-то, который Вы защищаете, один для всех?), почему он в \*p_conn - не понимаю.

Скорее всего у Вас память, адресуемая p_conn портится.

Comment: @avp,насчет вызова MD_PRT() из md_mutex_operation() Вы пожалуй правы, подумаю, как стоит это изменить.
в структуру p_conn у меня собраны несколько мьютексов. А зачем Вы бы его делали локальным? сообщения ведь постоянно в лог сыпятся, и тогда куча времени будет тратиться на его инициализацию каждый раз. Глобальным статическим я его пробовала сделать - результат абсолютно идентичный вышел.

Comment: @margosh, инициализировать мьютекс можно (да и, наверное, нужно) только один раз

    static pthread_mutex_t loglock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

прямо в теле md_prt().

Зачем его делать локальным? Просто для инкапсуляции. Это на самом деле ничего не решает, возможно только сужает "круг подозреваемых".

А глобальный статический Вы один раз инициализировали или есть ситуация, когда это делается повторно? Если да, то может быть проблема именно здесь.

Comment: глобальный инициализирую 1 раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ура! Переустановила Valgrind и обнаружила такое вот сообщение при установке :

> Known problems:
>         1) DRD/Helgrind tool gives excessive false-positivies for the
>            internals of pthreads library.  This is now under
>            investigation.
>         2) exp-ptrcheck tool doesn't work on FreeBSD now
>
> If you'll encounter any problems when using Valgrind do not
>         hesitate to contact the maintainer with the description of
>         these problems.

Думаю, это как раз о моих проблемах. Всем спасибо за помощь, avp особенно :) (учту Ваше замечание по поводу возможного повтора захватат блокировки)

Answer (score 1):

Как показывает практика, куда показывает valgrind там и следует искать ошибку. valgrind  с мьютексами работает нормально. Я бы посмотрел на код работающий с ними, возможно ошибка где-то там.

Можешь попробовать убрать на время все что можно, оставив лишь мьютексы и посмотреть как будет работать.

Comment: @mikelsv, добавила код функций. Если у Вас есть возможность, попробуйте прогнать у себя под Valgrind, плиз.